# jQuery if statement syntax

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I am trying to get a jQuery function to work on my Drupal 7 site, but I am having a difficult time to make it work.

This example works:

```
(function ($) {  

   Drupal.behaviors.theme = {

   attach: function (context, settings) {            

   $("#block-menu-3").css("background-color", "red");

   }

};})(jQuery);
```

But I am trying to do some a little more advanced stuff. For example: I want to apply black color to div B, only if div A is green.

So if I write

```
(function ($) {  

  Drupal.behaviors.theme = {

  attach: function (context, settings) {            

     $("div A").each(function(i){
       var color = $(this).css("background-color");
       if (color == "background-color:green;")
       $("div B").css("background-color", "");
       $("div B").css("background-color", "black");
     });

     }

 };})(jQuery);
```

Well it "works"....but div A could be any other color than green, and div B would become black under any circumstances....Im looking for the right way to wright the if statement....

So this does not work.....any help much obliged!

Comment: You missed the class or id operator. It should be like: `div .A`

Comment: is it `div .A` or `.divA` ?

Comment: actually it is #block-menu-3 and #block-menu-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working!

```
$("#block-menu-block-23").each(function(i){
   var color = $(this).css("background-color");
   if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color == 'blue'){
   alert('Hello jQuery');
   $("#block-block-15").css("background-color", "");
   $("#block-block-15").css("background-color", "red");
 }});
```

It was the parentesis after the if statement which was wrong.
So I did:

(color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)' || color == 'blue')

Instead of:

(color != "background-color:blue;")

But thank you guys for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

> div B would become black under any circumstances

That's because you're making it black outside of the `if` block:

```
if (color == "background-color:green;")
    $("div B").css("background-color", "");
$("div B").css("background-color", "black");
```

If both of those statements need to be in the `if` block then you need to use curly braces:

```
if (color == "background-color:green;") {
    $("div B").css("background-color", "");
    $("div B").css("background-color", "black");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this as well...nothing happens.

```
(function ($) {  

  Drupal.behaviors.theme = {

  attach: function (context, settings) {            

    $("#block-menu-block-23").each(function(i){
       var color = $(this).css("background-color");
       if (color == "background-color:green;"){
        alert('Hello jQuery');
       }
    });

 }

};})(jQuery);
```

And #block-menu-block-23 has background-color: green;